# Finding every complex number that fulfills |z| = 1 and $|\frac{z}{\bar z} + \frac{\bar z}{z} | = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wanna find out every complex number that fulfills $|z| =1 $ and  $$ |\frac{z}{\bar z} + \frac{\bar z}{z} | = 1$$

The first thing i do is that i expand both of the denominators with their conjugates and since $ |z| = 1$ i get that $ z * \bar z = |z|^{2} = 1 $

So i'm left with the following expression

$| z^{2}+(\bar z)^{2}|=1 $

The next thing i do is to change to polar form. Since $ |z|=1$, i get that
$$ z=|z|e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta} $$

and
$$ |e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta} | = 2|\frac{e^{i2\theta}+e^{-i2\theta}}{2}| = 2|cos(2\theta)|=1$$

Now, if i solve this i get 4 different complex numbers. However there should be 8 numbers so it seems that i lose answers somewhere or there is something im doing wrong that i can't seem to find.

Comment: Alt. hint: the second equation is equivalent to $\left(\frac{z}{\bar z}+\frac{\bar z}{z}\right)^2=1$.  When $|z|=1$ this gives $\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^2 = 1$ which factors into the product of two biquadratics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|\cos 2\theta| = 1/2$ for some real $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$, then $\cos 2\theta = \pm 1/2$. From a quick [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/shznrud8a7), I see eight solutions for $\theta$ (picture below). Did you drop your absolute value bars/forget the solutions corresponding to $-1/2$?

[image]

Comment: The way i did it was to split it into the two different cases so $|\cos 2\theta |= \frac{1}{2}$ and  $|\cos 2\theta |= \frac{-1}{2}$. Then for $|\cos 2\theta |= \frac{1}{2}$ i got $2\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi * k$. After dividing by two i then went over different integer values on k. when $k=2$ i got the same answer as when $k=0$. This gave me two solutions and doing the same for the solutions corresponding to $-\frac{1}{2}$ gave me two more, so 4 in total. However it seems like i have made an error and both cases have 2 more solutions each.

Comment: $2\theta = 2\pi k + \pi/3$ is right (equiv. $\theta = \pi k + \pi/6$), you just need to find all of the values of this form in the window $(-\pi,\pi]$. You observed $k = 0, 1$ give two solutions in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$, but so do $k = -1, -2$. Similarly for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

For real $x,x^2=|x|^2$

$$|\cos2t|=\dfrac12\implies\cos4t=\cdots=-\dfrac12$$

$$4t=360^\circ n\pm120^\circ$$ where $n$ is any integer

$t=90^\circ n\pm30^\circ$ where $0\le t<360^\circ$

$0\le90^\circ n-30^\circ<360^\circ\implies 1\le n\le4$

Similarly $0\le 90^\circ n+30^\circ<360^\circ\implies?$